# Qt keyboard enum to QString

Tags: qt

I have a piece of code like this  :

```
if(keyEvent->key()==Qt::Key_S && keyEvent->modifiers()==Qt::AltModifier) 
    {
        // my code
    }
```

I want to replace `Qt::Key_S` and `Qt::AltModifier` by two strings "KEY_S" and "ALT" which I intend to read from a file. I have no idea how to do it. I have tried `QKeySequence`, which is not working. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get the `Qt::Key` value in a `QKeyEvent` then just use [QKeyEvent::text()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#text) :

```
QString stringKey = event->text();
```

But as it is stated in the doc :

> Return values when modifier keys such as Shift, Control, Alt, and Meta
>   are pressed differ among platforms and could return an empty string.

So you might want to handle them one by one, just by giving them the string you want to associate :

```
if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Alt)
    QString stringKey = "ALT";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Qt meta object system to get real names of enum keys as strings at runtime:

```
void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* e) {
  int enum_index = qt_getQtMetaObject()->indexOfEnumerator("Key");
  const char* string = 
      qt_getQtMetaObject()->enumerator(enum_index).valueToKey(e->key());
  qDebug() << string;
}
```

Note that `valueToKey` may return null pointer if there is no corresponding key.